# unable to bind repeated div element separately - Typescript forEach

Tags: foreach

I want to render repeated div items as shown below

```html
<div class="item">Item 1</div>
<div class="item">Item 2</div>
<div class="item">Item 3</div>
```

But I am getting the output like this using the following code (Below Image links)

```html
<div class="item">Item 1
<div class="item">Item 2</div>
<div class="item">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

[The items are rendered  using the Items.forEach - Click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N92JZ.png)

[Binding is done to DIV id= notificationListContainer - Click here to view  the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZsjA.png)